# Is a supplement ticket required for international travel with Railjet to Austria?

Tags: trains, austria

When travelling between München and Salzburg, are all international train tickets valid for using the ÖBB Railjet service or is a special/supplement ticket required?

I am traveling with a ticket *RIT INCL. ICE* ticket issued by DB and was originally booked for a EuroCity connection between those two cities. If I would like to make a short stop in München, would it be possible to take the next Railjet train to Salzburg, or do need to travel with a EC-train?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DB treats the Railjet as an IC/EC train, no supplement is required.

While travel to Salzburg is basically treated as domestic German travel, even if you were traveling in Austria, the ÖBB doesn't distinguish ticketing between train classes except for in extremely discounted regional tickets (Einfach Raus Ticket can only be used on S, R, REX, ...), supplements don't exist in Austria.

(In regards to "are all [international] train tickets valid" the answer is no. Although your ticket is valid, there are a number of tickets that are either tied to a specific train / departure time or limited to regional trains.)

Comment: Though this is no longer always the case places like France and Italy, DB/ÖBB/SBB-CFF-FFS/MÁV/ČD still have an agreement to treat trains as domestic trains when they are in each company's respective country. This train will be treated as a DB train, including using DB ticketing conditions, between Munich and Salzburg even in the rolling stock or even the crew is Austrian.